# Keeping things decentralized Android

Tags: java, android

This might not make much sense in terms of Android SDK, but, in C++ I am used to keeping my main.cpp (and specifically main() function) as a place where I declare and initialize other classes/objects, and afterwards all the things that my application does take place in those classes. I never come back and check for anything in main.cpp afterwards. 
But in Java, Android SDK, you have to override dozens of methods in main activity and all of that takes place in one single file.  Example:

I have a MainActivity.java and SomeTest.java files in my project, where first is default MainActivity class which extends Activity, and SomeTest.java contains class that declares and runs new Thread. I initialize SomeTest class from MainActivity.java and pass a handle of the activity to it as a parameter:

```
SomeTest test = new SomeTest(MainActivity.this);
```

And having the handle to MainActivity, I proceed doing everything from this newly created thread. When I need to update the UI I use runOnUiThread() to create and show a new ListView (for example) on my main layout. I want to get the width and height of the newly created Listview, for what I have to override onWindowFocusChanged() in my MainActivity.java and notify the thread from there, as getWidth() and getHeight() will only have values when ListView is actually displayed on the screen. For me it's not a good practice to make such connections ('callbacks', if you will) from MainActivity to that thread.

Is there a way I can keep methods like onWindowFocusChanged() *within* the thread and don't touch the MainActivity.java at all?

As I said, might not make much sense.

Comment: +1 for asking a question I had never considered before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way I can keep methods like onWindowFocusChanged() within the thread and don't touch the MainActivity.java at all?

`onWindowFocusChanged()` is a callback method. It is called on the activity. You cannot change this.

> And having the handle to MainActivity, I proceed doing everything from this newly created thread.

That's generally not a good idea. Using a background thread to, say, load some data from a file or database is perfectly reasonable (though using `Loader` or `AsyncTask` may be better). However, usually, the background thread should neither know nor care about things like "the width and height of the newly created ListView".

You are certainly welcome to migrate some logic out of the activity and into other classes. You might use particular frameworks for that, such as fragments or custom views. However, the class structure should not be driven by your threading model. For example, let's go back to your opening statement:

> in C++ I am used to keeping my main.cpp (and specifically main() function) as a place where I declare and initialize other classes/objects, and afterwards all the things that my application does take place in those classes

However, in C++, you would not say that you are locked into only ever having two classes, one of which is operating on some background thread. While you may have a class or classes that happen to use a background thread (or threads), the driving force behind the class structure isn't "I have a background thread" but "I  want to reuse XYZ logic" or "I wish to use a class hierarchy in support of the strategy pattern" or some such.

Comment: Thank you. I get your point, however, consider this example:  I have a WebView that has a Javascript interface (bridge). When user clicks a certain button on my web page,  javascript code calls a certain method of the interface. From that method, I need to create and show a ListView on my layout. As WebView uses it's own thread, I have to use runOnUiThread() to achieve this. And there goes again my question on how would I get the width and height of the ListView within the same method where it is declared ?

Comment: @astralmaster: "From that method, I need to create and show a ListView on my layout" -- usually the `ListView` would already exist, and you would need to populate it on demand. "I have to use runOnUiThread() to achieve this" -- or `post()` on the `WebView`. Or `post()` on a `Handler`, if you have one for other reasons. "And there goes again my question on how would I get the width and height of the ListView withing the same method where it is declared ?" -- I would focus instead on getting rid of this "need", as most developers do not "need" this information to write their UIs.

Comment: @astralmaster: That being said, there is no way for you to "get the width and height of the ListView within the same method where it is declared ?", as the UI is message-based, and so creating the `ListView` does not actually put it on the screen until sometime after you return control to the OS. This is one of the reasons why developers typically try to avoid scenarios where they think they need to know the width and height of widgets, putting sizing rules in the layout XML resources instead.

Comment: That's basically what I was expecting. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Personally speaking `Context` idea taken from Android SDK seems to be messy. What you are describing comes from too much responsibility intended for `Activity`. That's why you need to track a LOT of things inside single file (`Activity`'s life cycle, getting `Context` instance in order to show `Dialog` etc.). I don't think there's perfect solution but I would recommend using:

- `Fragment` subclasses which are helping to divide your screen (and so on logic) into seperate parts
- 3rd party frameworks/libraries like [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/), [RoboGuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice), [Otto](http://square.github.com/otto/) which are perfect tools to avoid spaghetti code

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to perform some UI updates from another class, consider using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) passing it the Views you need to update. Let me know if you need an example

Answer (score 0):

I read everything and understand your statements, I can see you've been doing programming for sometime but apparently is just starting with Android, I've done a lot of embed systems before so I totally get the concept of having a software that looks like:

```
void run(){
    object.setup();
    while(true){
        otherObject.run();
    }
}
```

But there's one fundamental flaw on the you logic of your question:

**Android programming is a different programming paradigm from C++ and from computer programming and you should understand its specific paradigm instead of assume what is good practice from other paradigms.**

Quote from you: `create and show a new ListView (for example) on my main layout. I want to get the width and height of the newly created Listview, for what I have to override onWindowFocusChanged()`.

From that I can see that you've really trying to do Android stuff on a way that is not recommended on an Android context. A ListView you can easily implement from the XML layout `setContentView(int)` and use the Activity onCreate to instantiate any threading (AsyncTaskLoader) framework to load the data in background and deliver it back to the UI.

That doesn't mean that all your code will be dumped in one file making it a mess. This little example I put you can do with Activity that implements the loader callbacks, a separate class with the loader, a separate class with the data loading work, a separate class with the data adapter, the activity is just a central piece that organise and manage those classes on the correct moment of its life-cycle and at no point you need to call `onWindowFocusChanged()` and still have a nicely organised code.

Apart from that please refer to CommonsWare answer as it's usually cleverly written and correct.